# Actions on Google, BrowseCarousel UI is different in mobile in google assistant than the simulator

Tags: actions-on-google

I have tested the BrowseCarousel changes within action on google simulator, and it looks like grid carousel below,
  [layout on simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw5jA.png)

And If I try to check the same in my test device it shows as a list like below,
[layout on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17wYx.png)

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed the same with the Basic Cards.

Back at the start of October there was an important redesign of the interface, but seems like the documentation hasn't been updated yet.

Source:

https://www.theverge.com/2018/10/3/17931518/google-assistant-redesign-2018-new-features

https://techcrunch.com/2018/10/03/the-google-assistant-gets-more-visual/

https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/10/03/google-assistant-redesign-official-bigger-visuals-fresh-controls-new-tools-developers/